# Hydration error in Next.js 13 (Video included)

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I created a new next app and installed the newest version. I am testing out the app dir and encountered an error.

When I continually switch between the about and contact page and refresh the page at the same time like in [this video](https://streamable.com/mj7ueb)

This error shows up[image]

This only happens if the Footer component is added. If I remove the Footer component this will not happen

**app/about/page.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

import { Footer } from '../Footer'

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <>
            <Link href="/about">about</Link>
            <Link href="/contact">contact</Link>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

**app/contact/page.js**

```
import Link from 'next/link'

import { Footer } from '../Footer'

export default function Page() {
    return (
        <>
            <Link href="/about">about</Link>
            <Link href="/contact">contact</Link>
            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}
```

**app/footer.jsx**

```
export function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer>Footer</footer>
    )
}
```

[Github Repo](https://github.com/universe7000/next)

Comment: After cloning your repo I can't seem to reproduce this error. Try removing your `node_modules` directory and reinstalling via `npm i -D`.

Comment: @JasonRStevensCFA Did you spam refresh while switching the pages? To get the error, I had to spam (cmd+r) (refresh shortcut for mac) while clicking the links.

Comment: I followed your instructions and the error still occurs

Comment: ️ Doing a bunch of refreshes quickly led to reproducing the error.

Comment: I'm able to completely solve this by using a default export for the `Footer` component, rather than the named export, as indicated in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the error after following the OP's instructions to refresh quickly ("spam refresh") several times.

I am able to solve the error by making the `Footer` component exported in `Footer.jsx` a default export, rather than named export.

Simply change the function in `Footer.jsx` to read:

```
export default function Footer() {
  ...
}
```

And update the `Footer` imports within the pages, i.e.

```
// app/about/page.js
import Footer from '../Footer'
...
```

```
// app/contact/page.js
import Footer from '../Footer'
...
```

> ️ The `...` ellipses are for example, obviously not legitimate JavaScript! Replace with your code.

Comment: The error still seems to be happening. Sometimes it takes a while for it to appear. The error shows up quicker if you add prefetch=false to the links on both pages like : <Link prefetch={false} href="/about">about</Link>

Comment: If you add prefetch=false to all the links the error shows up by just alternating between the pages by clicking the links without having to refresh.

Comment: I think you're getting expected behavior in the local development environment. After changing the export to default there error is  _vastly_ less frequent on my end (several orders of magnitude less from what I can eyeball). The server is made to hot-reload in development. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli#development. This won't/can't happen in deployments.

Comment: In addition, the app directory is experimental, so be sure to report this via the link provided in your terminal so that Next devs can dig into this. I'd include a link to this question/answer set as well.